# MS word selecting the containing table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Is the an easy way to navigate from a call in a table to the table itself?
Or just easyly select the table itself? At time there is "+" apears that clicking it selects the table but at times clicking on places where I think is the edge of table to select it does not work.

In many environments if you are inside a nested element, pressing esc will navigate to outer contain element. What is the equivalent in word?

The reason I am asking is because I have pdf documents of bank statements opened in word and trying to convert the data in the tables to csv, I need to quickly select a table and convert it into csv, using words Table to text converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerator keys (shown on ribbon tabs) are ALT j l k t.  (The old Word 2003 and earlier shortcut keys also work ALT a c t)

Comment: Can you please include a reference or a snap shot of how you found this please?

Comment: When you press ALT key, you'll see letter(s) in a square appear in ribbon next to each item, indicating its accelerator keys.  The 2003 shortcut keys are ones I remember as I always use them (even now, as they're quicker than the extra ones needed for ribbon).